# Intelligently parse lists of people with organization information in Python

Tags: python, parsing

Suppose I have plaintext in the following format:

> John Doe, Suzy Q, Sue N. Sough and Michael Blanks, Wizards University, United Kingdom
>
> John Doe, Normal Place, Portugal and Suzy Q, Other Place, France
>
> John Doe and Suzy Q, Third Location, Germany
>
> John Doe, Suzy Q and Doug Z Doug, Fourth Location, Poland and Simon Pft, Fifth Location, Korea

Correctly parsed, the data should read something like:

```
[{
    'organization': "Wizards University",
    'country': "United Kingdom",
    'authors': ["John Doe", "Suzy Q", "Sue N. Sough", "Michael Blanks"]
}]


[ {
    'organization': "Normal Place",
    'country': "Portugal",
    'authors': ["John Doe"]
}, {
    'organization': "Other Place",
    'country': "France",
    'authors': ["Suzie Q"]
} ]


[{
    'organization': "Third Location",
    'country': "Germany",
    'authors': ["John Doe", "Suzy Q"]
}]


[ {
    'organization': "Fourth Location",
    'country': "Poland",
    'authors': ["John Doe", "Suzy Q", "Doug Z. Doug"]
}, {
    'organization': "Fifth Location",
    'country': "Korea",
    'authors': ["Simon Pft"]
} ]
```

It's pretty trivial for a human to look at this text and correctly parse it, but I'm wondering if there's a way to write a script that can read through and recognize when it's looking at a bunch of names listed together or not. I mean, starting from a dumb parser that just looks for commas and `and`s,

> John Doe, Suzy Q, Sue N. Sough and Michael Blanks, Wizards University, United Kingdom

looks just like

> John Doe, Normal Place, Portugal and Suzy Q, Other Place, France

and might be parsed thusly:

```
[{
    'organization': "Suzy Q",
    'country': "Sue N. Sough",
    'authors': ["John Doe"]
} , {
    'organization': "Wizards University",
    'country': "United Kingdom",
    'authors': ["Michael Blanks"]
}]
```

### Crucial and annoying addtion!

Country is not always given (ugh, I know!) especially when it is implied in the name of the organization.

So *sometimes* records will look like:

> John Doe, Suzy Q, Sue N. Sough and Michael Blanks, Wizards University
>
> John Doe, University of Portugal and Suzy Q, Other Place, France
>
> John Doe and Suzy Q, Third Location
>
> John Doe, Suzy Q and Doug Z Doug, Fourth Location, Poland and Simon Pft, Korea University

So while I might be able to use the country name (which is also formatted in non-standard ways, e.g. Korea, S. Korea, Republic of Korea, etc) for some records it wouldn't work for all.

#### What I ended up doing…

…was using the smartest pattern recognition tool I know -- me. I just scanned through the document with a regex search-and-replace that looked for `\s*(,|&|\band\b)\s*` and if it was between names I replaced it with `|` and if it was between groups of names I replaced it with `;`. Fortunately the data set was small enough (well under 100 total) that the time spent was less than it would have taken for me to write an intelligent-enough parser. I *did* get started with a Bayesian classifier that did an okay job of distinguishing between people's names vs. organizations, but it still misidentified one or the other often enough that it wouldn't have worked for my purposes.

Comment: You would very definitely have to maintain a list of countries, if not additionally a list of organizations, if you can't depend on some kind of consistent formatting, which it looks like you cant.

Comment: It's not *that* trivial, even for a human. I would have to (and I do) maintain a list of names and have an internal likelihood function which weighs the probability that a given phrase is a name vs the probability that it's an organization/country, etc.

Comment: Try something Bayesian, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If the country is in always last and the organization is the previous element, then you can consider others as name, as well as you can easily write some code by splitting through 'and' & ','.

Comment: The OP already considers the parsing of connecting elements *in* the question.

Comment: sorry I didn' understand at first. Did you try Markov Chain models for bigram or trigram? I hope it would bring some expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I think Shasan is on the right track. The country name defines the end of a unit. The second to last token (split out by ',') is the company name, and the rest of the tokens are names.

A use-case that would break this is if you had two people-company tuples within the same country, as in:

> John Doe, Normal Place, and Suzy Q, Other Place, France

Also, if there are commas that are part of the company name in your text. Quotes might be used to protect these.

Answer (score -1):

```
l=Line.split(",")
Row = {
    "Org": l[-2],
    "Ctry": l[-1],
    "Authors": l[:-2]
}
```